# Inspiration for the Newsroom?

Tags: character, the-newsroom

Was *The Newsroom's* cast inspired by real personalities, since I know that many of the story-lines were based on true news events, but could find no reference to the inspiration behind the lead cast members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aaron Sorkin answered this question in an interview with Vulture magazine on June 2012.
Contrary to his previous show *Sports Night*, where the news were made up, in The Newsroom

> *<< ...the news events will always be real. To make the place seem real, you want to see shards of a news broadcast, you want to see them in
>   rundown meetings, you want to see them doing the job, getting the
>   news. With Sports Night, it was fairly easy to make up fake news that
>   sounded real. All you had to do was say, “And now, the Jets injury
>   report: So-and-so has a torn ACL,” and you’d cut away >>*

With regards to the question if the characters were based on real life people, he said that:

> *<< let’s be really clear about this—no character on the show is based, even a little bit, on anyone from real life. Okay? Anyone. Jeff Daniels is not playing Keith Olbermann. Will bears no resemblance to Keith Olbermann >>*

Here's the link to the [**interview**](http://www.vulture.com/2012/06/aaron-sorkin-newsroom-interview.htmlhttp://www.vulture.com/2012/06/aaron-sorkin-newsroom-interview.html?utm_source=huffingtonpost.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=pubexchange_article)

Keith Olbermann however has a different opinion:

> *<< This may come as a surprise to Olbermann, who allowed Sorkin to spend several weeks "embedded with" his "Countdown" show during the BP
>   Oil Spill in 2010. Last week, Olbermann told told The New York
>   Times that he believes "The Newsroom" was at least somewhat influenced
>   by his experience on cable news. "This is the second show he's done
>   about my life ...At least this one, I knew I saw it coming. >>*

[(**source**)](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/06/17/the-newsroom-aaron-sorkin_n_1604190.html)